# Bedeutung vom Ausdruck "als es wieder so weit war"

Tags: meaning, phrase

Was bedeutet eigentlich der Ausdruck "als es wieder so weit war", z.B. in einem Satz wie:

> Einmal als es wieder so weit war, hatten wir 50 Verwandte zu Besuch

Mit Google habe ich viele Stellen gefunden, in denen der Ausdruck vorkommt, konnte aber nach den Zusammenhängen keine genaue Bedeutung ablesen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Als es wieder soweit war...

ist auf einene Zeitpunkt gelegt, der wiederkehren ist (Geburtstag, Weihnachten, Familienfest...).

Mit "Einmal..." wählt man ein solches Ereignis aus, dass in der Vergangenheit aufgetreten ist (bei diesem einen Mal waren *50 Verwandte* zu Besuch).

## Beispiele:

> "An meinem Geburtstag lade ich immer einige Freunde ein. **Einmal, als es wieder soweit war**, kamen sagenhafte 50 Freunde zu meiner Geburtstagsparty. Soviele kamen noch nie!"

(*"...soweit war," ist hier auf den Geburtstag bezogen*)

---

> "Ich mag die Schule nicht besonders. **Einmal, als es wieder soweit war**, musste ich nach den langen Ferien wieder in die Schule, und ich verschlief am Morgen prompt"

(*"...soweit war," ist hier auf den Schlubeginn gezogen*)

---

> "Immer Ende Semester habe ich Semesterprüfungen. **Einmal, als es wieder soweit war**, verpasste ich den Zug und kam zu spät zum Prüfungsbeginn."

(*"...soweit war," ist hier auf die Semesterprüfungen Ende Semester bezogen*)

---

> "Am Wochenende spielt immer mein Lieblingsfussballverein. **Einmal, als es wieder soweit war**, kamen so viele Zuschauer, das ich der Start verpasste, weil ich so lange anstehen musste".

(*"...soweit war," ist hier auf das Fussballspiel vom Wochenende bezogen)*

---

Comment: *`dass in der Vergangenheit aufgetreten`* -- *einmal* weist nicht nur in die Vergangenheit. Es ist auf jeden Fall nicht *jetzt*. Vergleiche z.B. *einmal werden auch wir gewinnen*

Comment: Hm. Ehrlich gesagt, die Sache ist immer noch nicht klar. Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, dürfte also "als es wieder soweit war" ganz einfach weggelassen werden, da der Ausdruck gar nichts zu den Ausdrücken "einmal" bzw. "eines Tages" hinfügt. Bin ich da richtig?

Comment: Nein, "als es wieder soweit war" bezieht sich auf etwas, das *wiederkehrend* ist (mehrmaliges auftreten). Es hat nichts mit "einmal" oder "eines Tages" zu tun. Es kann jedoch zusammen in Verbindung gebracht werden. "Eines Tages, als es wieder soweit war...". Jedoch *nur* "einmal" bzw. "eines Tages" bezieht sich nicht auf ein wiederkehrendes Ereignies wie bei "als es wieder soweit war...". Mit "einmal" bzw. "eines Tages" referenziert man auf einen undefinierten- (*einmal*) respektive definierten (*eines Tages*) Zeitpunkt. Hoffe jetzt ist es klarer...